# Как обратиться к динамическому обьекту gtkmm

Tags: c++, c++11, label, gtkmm3

```
CryptoMonitor::CryptoMonitor()
{  
    mainBox = new Gtk::VBox;

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) { 
        mainBox->pack_start(*new Gtk::Label(getValue(getResponse(API_URL), i)));
    } 

    add(*mainBox);

    vector<Gtk::Widget*> v;

    v = mainBox->get_children();

    ???
}
```

Имеется код на C++ (бибилиотека gtkmm). mainBox наполняется обьектами типа Gtk::Label. На выходе get_children() получаю обьекты типа Gtk::Widget*. Как мне обратиться к методам Gtk::Label?? С помощью простого индекса не выходит, как-как компилятор воспринимает это как обращение к методам из Gtk::Widget*. Мне же надо сделать чтото типа:

```
v[0].set_text("Текст в Label под индексом 0");
```

Comment: правильное решение — при наполнении сохранять указатели на объекты, с которыми будешь взаимодействовать.

Comment: И правда. Спасибо. Очень помогли